# multiple definition of Class with member function definition inside and outside

Tags: c++

On defining a class in two object (or more) files with identical definitions with the member function(s)
defined outside the class (with no `inline` qualification) then I got a multiple definitions error.

But on defining the function inside or outside with `inline` - does the linkage of class becomes internal so that each object file would have separate copies of class?

Is there any limitations to this as the compiler doesn't `inline` function with big size or function which are not called frequently?

Comment: C++  `inline` keyword is not directly related to function inlining performed by the compiler. `inline` keyword is mostly about the One-Definition Rule. That said, why are you defining the same function in multiple translation units?

Comment: @UnholySheep I am just trying to check the limits and find where-why the code has gone wrong

Comment: I don't really understand how that is related to having multiple definitions of functions. Perhaps you can provide a [mcve] to showcase what you are attempting to do (and why)

Comment: The class has no linkage. (Member) functions have.